# How to choose the port spring-boot-admin will use?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

My application has two http port. One for business and the second with actuator. Spring-Boot-Admin chooses the first and it doesn't seem to work, because, I guess, admin need an actuator to work.

How to configure admin to choose right port?

Comment: Can you share your `application.properties` please?